# No funcionan las condiciones múltiples

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función que recibe parámetros, lo que va a recibir es un `string` tipo: `llffllfrfb`, quiero separar cada carácter ya que `l` es una función, `r` es otra, `f` es otra y `b` es otra.

Hasta aquí, mi código funciona genial.

```
function comandos(commands){
  for(var i = 0; i < commands.length; i++){
      console.log(commands[i])
      if(commands[i] !== 'l' || commands[i] !== 'r'){
        console.log('Command not valid');
      } else{
      switch(commands[i]){
      case 'l':
      turnLeft(rover.direction);
      break;

      case 'r':
      turnRight(rover.direction);
      break;

      case 'f':
      rover.travelLog.push([rover.x , rover.y]);
      moveForward(rover.direction);
      break;

      case 'b':
      moveBackward();
      rover.travelLog.splice((rover.travelLog.length - 1) ,1);
      break;
    }   
    }
  }
 console.log(rover.travelLog)
}
```

Quiero validar que el dato que se le pasa por parámetro, si no es ni `l` ni `r`, ni `f` ni `b` muestre un `console.log` diciendo que no es un comando válido. Si en la condición uso: `if(commands[i] !== 'l')` me funciona perfectamente, pero si le añado el OR, ya, todas son "comando no válido".

¿dónde está el error?

Comment: los `switch` tienen una opcion `default` que se ejecuta cuando ninguna de las otras condicionales se cumplieron que resulta perfecta para tu caso así no tienes que agregar el `if` previo que utilizas, lo puedes resolver todo con el `switch`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu error es usar OR en lugar de AND.

Si `commands[i] = 'r'`, entonces el programa haría:

1. ¿`commands[i] !== 'l'`? Verdadero. Así que ni evaluará la otra condición (verdadero OR cualquier cosa = verdadero).

Si `commands[i] = 'l'`, entonces haría:

1. ¿`commands[i] !== 'l'`? Falso. Así que evaluará la otra condición.
2. ¿`commands[i] !== 'r'`? Verdadero. Así que entra en el if (falso OR verdadero = verdadero).

Ponlo con AND:

`if (commands[i] !== 'l' && commands[i] !== 'r')` Así compruebas que no es ni 'l' ni 'r'.

---

## OR

```
+-------+---------------+---------------+-----------------------------------+
| letra | letra !== 'l' | letra !== 'r' | (letra !== 'l' OR letra !== 'r') |
+-------+---------------+---------------+----------------------------------+
|   l   |     false     |     true      |    false OR true = true          |
|   r   |      true     |    false      |    true OR false = true          |
|   a   |      true     |     true      |     true OR true = true          |
+-------+---------------+---------------+----------------------------------+
```

## AND

```
+-------+---------------+---------------+-----------------------------------+
| letra | letra !== 'l' | letra !== 'r' | (letra !== 'l' AND letra !== 'r') |
+-------+---------------+---------------+-----------------------------------+
|   l   |     false     |     true      |    false AND true = false         |
|   r   |      true     |    false      |    true AND false = false         |
|   a   |      true     |     true      |      true AND true = true         |
+-------+---------------+---------------+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Ahora lo veo!!!.. Muchas gracias Arian..

Comment: @Adrián si la respuesta te valió es mejor que [la aceptes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas), así se cierra la pregunta. Además, nos dan reputación a los dos :-)

Comment: Sí, perdona, pero en el momento que te escribí no me dejaba marcarla como buena, tenía que esperar un tiempo. Ya está marcada! gracias! por la explicación que has añadido!